# Arabic text is seperated in PDF file using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I created a simple code that create a pdf file that contains text and its working fine only when I use English text but the issue is when I use Arabic text became separated like this: ا ل س ل ا م ع ل ي ك م

but the letters should be connected like this: السلام عليكم

here is my code with arabic text, any help will be very appreciated.

```
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim fontLoc = "C:\Users\Win 10\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\ScheherazadeRegOT.ttf"


    Dim basef As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontLoc, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, True)

    Dim arabicfont As New iTextSharp.text.Font(basef, 24, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)
    Dim el As New Chunk()
    Dim arabicfont2 As New iTextSharp.text.Font(basef, 16, el.Font.Style, el.Font.Color)
    el.Font = arabicfont2


    Dim pdfPTable As New PdfPTable(1)
    Dim pdfDoc As New Document()


    Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("C:\Users\Win 10\Desktop\mjh.pdf", FileMode.Create))
    pdfDoc.Open()
    pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph(StrReverse("السلام عليكم"), el.Font))

    'Launch the document if you have a file association set for PDF's 
    Dim AcrobatReader As Process = New Process
    AcrobatReader.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Users\Win 10\Desktop\mjh.pdf"
    AcrobatReader.Start()

    pdfDoc.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You are using iText 5.x and in that version arabic shapping and reordering is only done in PdfPTable and ColumnText.

Comment: thanksa Paulo Soares,  do you have an example

Comment: Google is your friend, here's one: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/221250/problem-with-iTextSharp-arabic-text.